# "There is no data for this view." in reports with custom dimensions in Measurement Protocol of Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, report, measurement-protocol

Our application needs to gather usage data through the Measurement Protocol of Google Analytics.

We can successfully send "appview" hits to the Google Analytics server, and get a proper response by it (a GIF image). The appview hits appear on the GA Dashboard, along with the country of origin, session duration, etc.

We also have several custom dimensions and metrics that we want track for each hit. We have set those up in the GA Admin panel with the correct scope, index and active state. We have 3 Hit-scoped dimensions, 3 User-leveled dimensions and 1 Hit-scoped metric, all set to Active state.

We send the dimensions and metrics as described in the docs at

[Custom Dimensions / Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#customs)

attached to the hits they apply for, like so:

```
...&cm1*=3    <--for the metric
```

and

```
...&cd6*=15   <--for the dimensions (some dimensions have numeric values, others are text)
```

The problem is that those metrics and dimensions don't show up in our custom reports: the reports always say `"There is no data for this view."`. For example, we have a report that has one dimension and one metric, without any filters, set to "Any view". It doesn't matter if the Type of the report is Explorer, Flat Table or Map Overlay, it never shows anything.

There have been several days since the hits were received and appeared in the dashboard, but the reports are still empty. So scratch out any processing lag.

We tried sending "`event`" hits instead of "`appview`" hits - again, the hits show up in the Dashboard, but the reports are empty.

We cannot get any useful insights without using dimensions and metrics - so there is no way to get by without this.

Because of reasons too long to describe, we cannot use any of the Google-provided Analytics libraries.

Is there anything else we need to do to see data in those reports?

Comment: Do you see the hits come in while looking at the Realtime report? also try omitting the * from parameter for example: ...&cd1=14&cm2=3

Comment: Hey, I can swear there were * asterisks in the protocol docs last time I checked them! It seems that Google changed the docs. It is very likely that this is the real reason for the problem. Unfortunately, I'm no longer working on this feature so I can't really test. Can anyone can confirm this works?

Comment: @Matt is right, no asterisks https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#customs

Answer (score 0):

When using the measurement protocol you need to that the profile is not set to exclude bot and spiders.

Go to the google analytics website under the admin and the settings under the profile in question.

[image]

Beyond that check the realtime reports you should see the hits coming in.  You will need to wait 24 -48 hours for data to appear in the standard reports due to data processing lag.